# Why is IE8 making problems?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

Here is the code for my menu. The problem is that in Mozilla and Chrome .. everything is perfect. But IE8 doesn't view my menu as i want. I set padding but it acts as if there i no padding. That is when mouseover the red backround is really only let's say line.. and it should be like a box!

```
<div class="section" id="navbar">
                        <div class="nav">
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">About</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Ressources</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Gallery</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
//some other code
</div>
```

And here is the css:

```
.nav{margin:25px 0 0 180px;}
.nav li{
list-style-type:none;
display:inline-block;
float:left;
color:#910808;

}
.nav li:hover{
background-color:#910808;
color:#ffffff;
}
.nav li a{
text-decoration:none;
border-top:2px solid #910808;
color:#910808;
background-color:none;
padding:15px;
}

.nav li a:hover{
text-decoration:none;
color:#ffffff;
background-color:#910808;
}

#navbar{
width:980px;
height:58px;
}
```

Comment: IE8 doesn't understand HTML5 elements without some help from JavaScript. https://code.google.com/p/html5shim/

Comment: padding in I.E. can behave differently in html5.

Comment: Who uses IE8 anymore?????

Comment: IE8 won't apply padding to inline elements such as `a` (i.e., `.nav li a`). You can fix this by changing the `display` to `inline-block`, but that's likely to cause more problems than it solves.

Comment: Having problems with any version of IE is normal and expected.

Comment: @ceejayoz He's not using HTML5 elements in his example.

Comment: @Rob You appear to have missed the part of the question that goes `Why does IE8 denies the tag? my whole header was in this tag but it properties didnt show in Explorer until i changed it with . And that even when i declared in the css **header**,div,nav{display:block;`.

Comment: @ceejayoz I didn't miss it but that part did confuse me in that it doesn't make sense and it's not in his example. Your comment about HTML5 elements in IE, however, is correct.

Comment: I'd guess he didn't have luck with the `<header>` tag and thus switched to a div.

Comment: yes.. i just put the div instead of header tag and it worked... but i should use that link so that ie understands html5

Comment: "Stoopid is as stoopid does, sir" - IE Gump

Comment: fix `header,div,nav{display:block;}` to read `header,div,.nav{display:block;}`. `nav` is a class and must be preceeded by a "."

Comment: You have already accepted an answer. There is no need to do anything further.

Comment: Well i tried to close the question but I couldnt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you have a inline style on the main div that holds everything that says its a 1000px. Every element within it has this same width. This will not work in all browsers as you are experiencing. **Try using percentages** for width on the **inner divs** like 50% (this number is just a guess ... it will depend on how big your margins/padding is).

The reason this is the case is that margins and padding are being factored into all your `divs` as well as for the main div. You are attempting to fit a div inside a div with the same width. Both the `divs` have default margins/paddings. In addition, you have explicitly declared some padding which is having a unexpected applied behavior.

**Update**

Add property:

```
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
 box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
```

But note this **won't work** in Internet Explorer below version 8.

OR

**Put a div in your newdiv with width: auto; and margin-left: 15px;**

**Remove the padding from newdiv.**

[The W3 Box model page has good info.](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html)

Comment: i tried to apply your advices and after some changes it still doesnt work perfectly.

.nav{width:50%; margin:25px 0 0 180px; height:60px;border:1px    solid blue;margin-top:10px;}
.nav li{
list-style-type:none;
color:#910808;
float:left;
}

#navbar{
border:1px solid orange;
width:980px;
}

.search{
margin:-50px 20px 0 0;
width:25%;
border:1px solid yellow;
float:right;
display:inline;
}

That's it.. And still i think that ie does not understands the float:left property. When i put instead in nav class display:inline,  there shows some padding. Although you still cant see the top border of nav.

Comment: Much appreciated but think it doesn't work... Since i can not upload here a picture, i did so elsewhere and ... so you can see what's the problem. Above(on the picture) is chrome, below ie8.

www freeimagehosting net/a2i4i

Comment: Ask question with that image. I wish I could fix this problem.